# Cannot run SailsJS app with forever

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sails.js, forever

I am installing an SailsJS app on an Amazon Ubuntu instance.

If I run the app with `sails lift` everything works and the program run successfully. Now I try to run it through `forever` for obvious reasons. As specified by the SailsJS documentation I run forever on the app.js file located at the root of my project : `forever start app.js`

But that time the app fails :

```
forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script forever pid   id logfile                        uptime  
data:    [0] XXXX /usr/bin/nodejs app.js 15348   15350    /home/ubuntu/.forever/XXXX.log STOPPED
```

Logfile contains only :

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
```

Any idea why `sails lift` would work but not with `forever` ?

Comment: First try to check if running `node app.js` (instead of sails lift) works, it probably won't, i don't think is a forever issue.

Comment: Yes you are right ! And it does not provide more logs.

Comment: You mean is not throwing an error? Try `node app.js --verbose` and check carefully the console, there should be something that can point you to where the issue lies. Also update your question with your sails configuration (like adapters, etc) and the error thrown, so you get more chances of getting help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are permissions errors. Try to verify forver's permissions files in .forever directory or maybe run with sudo.

I run `forever start app.js` with sudo and I did't have any problems.

After that `sudo forever list` a get:

```
data:    [0] kBdX /usr/bin/nodejs app.js 23533   23538    /home/ubuntu/.forever/kBdX.log 0:0:34:28.312
```